# Why is PHP printing my number in scientific notation, when I specified it as .000021?

Tags: php, syntax, formatting, numbers

In PHP I have the following code:

```
<?PHP
  $var = .000021;
  echo $var;
?>
```

the output is 2.1E-5  !

Why? it should print .000021

Answer (score 66):

Use [number_format()](http://php.net/function.number_format) to get what you're after:

```
print number_format($var, 5);
```

Also check [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 28):

2.1E-5 *is* the same number as 0.000021.  That's how it prints numbers below 0.001.  Use [printf()](https://www.php.net/printf) if you want it in a particular format.

**Edit** If you're not familiar with the `2.1E-5` syntax, you should know it is shorthand for 2.1×10<sup>-5</sup>.  It is how most programming languages represent numbers in scientific notation.

Answer (score 16):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) or [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) if you want to see the number as you expect.

```
echo sprintf('%f', $var);
echo number_format($var, 6);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern".  There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Comment: Perfectly valid when giving an example of what the sprintf() function does. This is isn't full code, just a one line to show what a function does.

Answer (score 11):

To show a number up to 8 decimal spaces, without extra zeroes to the right (as number_format does, which can be annoying), use this:

```php
echo rtrim(rtrim(sprintf('%.8F', $var), '0'), ".");
```

Answer (score 10):

In general, a number is a number, not a string, and this means that any programming language treats a number as a number. Thus, the number by itself doesn't imply any specific format (like using `.000021` instead of `2.1e-5`). This is nothing different to displaying a number with leading zeros (like `0.000021`) or aligning lists of numbers. This is a general issue you'll find in any programming language: if you want a specific format you need to specify it, using the format functions of your programming language.

Unless you specify the number as string and convert it to a real number when needed, of course. Some languages can do this implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers responded to OP question, but none offered the code to do it.
Use this function to format any number with **E-** format.

```
function format_amount_with_no_e($amount) {
    $amount = (string)$amount; // cast the number in string
    $pos = stripos($amount, 'E-'); // get the E- position
    $there_is_e = $pos !== false; // E- is found

    if ($there_is_e) {
        $decimals = intval(substr($amount, $pos + 2, strlen($amount))); // extract the decimals
        $amount = number_format($amount, $decimals, '.', ','); // format the number without E-
    }

    return $amount;
}
```

Please note the function will always return a string.

Answer (score 3):

I created a function like the one below, which seems to be working fine.

```
function convertExponentialToDecimal($number) {

  $full_string = $number;

  $is_exponential = preg_match('/^\$?[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?[Ee][+-]?\d+$/i', $full_string ); // check if the number is in exponential notation
  if ($is_exponential) {
    
      $decimal = sprintf("%.20f", $full_string );
      $decimal = bcmul($decimal, '1', 20);
      $decimal = rtrim($decimal, '0');
      $decimal = rtrim($decimal, '.');

  } else {
      $decimal = (float)$full_string;
  }

  return $decimal;

}
```

This function can convert the exponential values to a whole number (in decimal notation).

```
echo convertExponentialToDecimal('6.20503e-7');
```

The above code gives a result of **0.000000620503**.

I don't know if this is the proper solution or not; however, it is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages have different methods for storing numbers in memory.  This is determined by the type of number that is being used.  In your case, you have a floating point number (a fraction) that is to large to be stored as a fixed point number ( fractions are stored in this manner depending on their size).

This is a very important feature especially when working with very large or very small numbers.  For instance, NASA or spaceX uses special storage methods for its calculations to ensure that the rockets the re-enter earths orbit land where they should.

Also, different storage methods take up different amounts of memory.  However, the solution provided above should work.  Just remember round off errors might occur with very big or small numbers.