# Big Numbers In PHP

Tags: php, numbers

I have fb_id **100001635692408** in my database but when I get it in my PHP script it prints something like this **1.0000163569241E+14**. And how can I get that number without convertation?

Comment: `string` is not good ? you're doing some math with those large numbers?

Comment: A string should be used, but I fail to see the problem: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8xCOlO

Comment: Nothing were converted, it's a different reprensentation of the same name: `100 = 10 * 10 = 100 * 1 = 1 * 100` ;) However: I recommend a string too

Comment: It's too small of an edit for me to legitimately make, but the word you were looking for was "conversion".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is PHP printing my number in scientific notation, when I specified it as .000021?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471674/why-is-php-printing-my-number-in-scientific-notation-when-i-specified-it-as-00)

Comment: @MarekSebera: it's an index column in a database, there are tons benchmarks (I know, there not always representative of real life) that show a significant speed advantage of numeric indexing over strings (some claim 5x faster, but I'd say twice is realistic). SQL does `<` and `>` comparison operations all the time, for that, numeric types are, which ever way you look at it, better. @Shako: don't convert your index to strings, please... just don't

Comment: so you're suggesting a unique (and somehow not indexed) varchar field? That just "doesn't compute", IMHO. Besides: an `autoincrement` primary key is all right on simple myIsam tables, but in scenarios where table locking (e.g. replication, triggers, foreign keys, etc...) it's a nightmare, but this is going rather off topic... Let's agree to disagree :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

store fb_id as string format in database.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
number_format($myNum, 0, "");
```

This will display your number without commas (the third parameter is the separator) or decimals (that's what the second parameter is for).

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the ID as a string, especially Facebook ids which can be alphanumeric for some objects. These IDs may also be larger than what some machines can store as an integer at some point, a la what happened with a lot of Twitter apps.

You'll also never use this data as an integer. You'd never add to IDs together, or check if one is greater than the other. So int/number really is the wrong type here.