# php get full number

Tags: php, for-loop, numbers

I am trying to get full 16 dight numbers. My php code:

```
for ($x = 4200000000000000; $x <= 4300000000000000; $x++) 
{
echo $x; die;
}
```

I want to get: 4200000000000001 but it returns me: 4.2E+15

Comment: To make supplementations to your question you can edit it instead.

Comment: you need to use number_format function; what you're getting is a scientific notation. http://us.php.net/function.number_format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format) or [printf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

See also:
[Why is PHP printing my number in scientific notation, when I specified it as .000021?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471674/why-is-php-printing-my-number-in-scientific-notation-when-i-specified-it-as-00)

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($x = 4200000000000000; $x <= 4200000000000005; $x++) {
    echo number_format($x, 0, '.', ''); 
}
```

Comment: explanation would be great

Answer (score 0):

If you echo with number_format, you can force the format you want:

```
echo number_format($x, 0, '', '');
```

I stated no decimal point and no commas with the empty strings.