# how to get decimal number without fractional part round down from php object (precision)

Tags: php, object

I have a an object like

`{"latitude":-37.81425094604492, "longitude":144.96316528320312}`

and I obtain

`$latitude = $myobj->latitude;`

but the value that is returned is -37.814250946045 , with 12 digits fractional part (rounded to 12 digits from the original 14)

how can I obtain the actual -37.81425094604492 with all 14 digits and no rounding?

Comment: The only way I've seen is to convert them to strings in the JSON (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759547/1213708 although may need some adjustments to the regex).  Not ideal, but at least it gives the values.

Comment: @NigelRen is right, the only way to get the "full" number without conversion to float and losing precision is, to edit the json, so php parses them as strings.

Comment: yes gives values but does not account for negatives - if anyone wants to post a regex that works ill accept as answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - float numbers wrong precision with json\_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509864/php-float-numbers-wrong-precision-with-json-decode)

Comment: yes that did the trick - $latitude = number_format($myobj->latitude,14);

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to keep the serialization precision to 17, and this is a reasonable and feasible precision.

In *php.ini* , there are configuration argument *precision* looks like this:

```
; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
precision = 14
```

Change it to what you want, like:

```
precision = 17
```

And the json_decode should keep the precision you need.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: thanks tgarm - good answer but prefer not to have to edit the php.ini file - the number_format solution works best