# PHP: Small Floating numbers are converted in scientific notation (E)

Tags: php, apache

I have switched to ios and I have a weird problem when the server is displaying small numbers with precision points. So the following number for example:

```
0.000036
```

is represented like this when I var_dump it:

```
3.6E-5
```

How can I turn off this cause it's confusing to work in this notation?

Update:

I know with **number_format** I can display the number but in Windows there was no need... Is this some IOS settings that is doing it and can it be turned off?

Comment: just 2 second search on google  http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is PHP printing my number in scientific notation, when I specified it as .000021?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471674/why-is-php-printing-my-number-in-scientific-notation-when-i-specified-it-as-00)

Answer (score 1):

[number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
<?php
$num = 0.000036;
echo number_format($num,6);
?>
```

or, no matter how long the number is it would do it automatically for you

```
<?php
$num = 0.000036;
$length = strlen($num);
echo number_format($num,$length -1);
?>
```

Comment: That's the thing I don't want to format each time the number. Isn't there a way to display it automatically. I mean in Windows it was OK without number_format...

Comment: Are the numbers always 0. something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are var_dumping the variable, you can use [printf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) to get it in the format you want without having to stipulate the decimal places you want it to:

```
  $var = 0.000036;
  var_dump(printf('%f', $var));
```

Comment: The only problem with this method is that calls it an int(8). I currently have bored kids jumping over me, wish I could tailor it more for you, but hopefully this is enough for you.