# PHP E Scientific Notation

Tags: php

Can someone help me remove this E scientific notation as I've googled everything and I can't resolve my problem?

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
  </body>
</html>

<?php
echo 'Generation took: ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . ' seconds';
?>
```

As a result, I get my seconds for the load time but the E at the end is what I want to remove. Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is PHP printing my number in scientific notation, when I specified it as .000021?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471674/why-is-php-printing-my-number-in-scientific-notation-when-i-specified-it-as-00)

Comment: I don't know howto use that code provided for my code. I suck at php as I've never used it before. I want it to print in seconds

Comment: If you don't know the meaning of your codes, please try to read the documentation. PHP documentation is easy to understand.

Comment: Appears to be pretty much the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64922351/microtime-php-random-e, but with added “account hopping”?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to get rid of the E part.

Please use the number_format function.

Say if you want 10 decimal places, please try the following:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
  </body>
</html>

<?php
echo 'Generation took: ' . number_format((microtime(true) - $start),10) . ' seconds';
?>
```

Comment: though the last echo line should be put inside the HTML structure, otherwise the output will be weird. If the OP doesn't know how many decimal places in his value, it's better to format the value via: `sprintf('%f', $val);`, which avoided the hardcoded `10` value.

Comment: Is this printing the seconds? Say I took 1.2 seconds to load the page, wouldn't it say 1.02 seconds loaded or something