# PHP Numeric calculation e-5 e-6

Tags: php

When I multiply two numbers with php I get results like 3.12E-5 0.15E-6
How can I make these numbers like 0.0000010212?

Example

```
$amount = "100.00"; <<--- Variable
$bitcoin = "0.00000312"; <<--- Variable
$calculation = $amount * $bitcoin;
echo $calculation;
// Result : 3.12E-5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is PHP printing my number in scientific notation, when I specified it as .000021?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471674/why-is-php-printing-my-number-in-scientific-notation-when-i-specified-it-as-00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of the `BC Math` functions for things like this. In this example I've used `bcmul()` to multiply the values and provided `8` as the scale to support a single satoshi:

```
$amount = "100.00"; 
$bitcoin = "0.00000312";
$calculation = bcmul($amount, $bitcoin, 8);
echo $calculation; //0.00031200
```

Comment: Thank you. The number after the number 8?

Answer (score 0):

```
$amount = floatval("100.00"); 
$bitcoin = floatval("0.00000312");
$calculation = $amount * $bitcoin;
$calculation = number_format($calculation,6,'.',',');
echo $calculation;
```

Comment: $coinPrice = floatval($output["BTC"]) * floatval($payment->amount);
Unfortunately it didn't work //

Comment: Float math for financial things isn't a good idea. Better to calculate in Satoshis and cents.

Comment: @insightwebtechnet what is the value of $output["BTC"] and $payment->amount? I ran the PHP code https://www.writephponline.com/ and it worked, I think it will be helpful if you share the inputs.

Comment: @CWilliams amount = 100.00 output[btc] = 0.00000312